# Highlight Arrival Date to Departure Date Asp Calendar

Tags: c#, asp.net

How can i highlight Dates from StartDate to EndDate using asp Calendar C#

when i first Click a Date to Calendar it will be the first Date and when i Click another Date i will be the last Date and highlights the Date

from StartDate to EndDate

this is the example
http://reservations.directwithhotels.com/reservation/selectDates/171

when he click first it will be the Arrival then when he clicks a date again it will be the Departure and its highlight all the date between Arrival and Departure Date

anyone knows how to do it int ASP Calendar C#?

Answer (score 0):

you can try with this code by using DayRender

```
protected void Calendar_DayRender(object sender, DayRenderEventArgs e)
    {
            if (e.Day.Date > startDate && 
                e.Day.Date < finishDate     ) //Adjust your condition on  e.Day.Date
            {
                e.Cell.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green; //Highligth ; adjust your color
            }
        }
    }



protected void Calendar1_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
   if(startDate == null)
     startDate = Calendar1.SelectedDate;
   else
     finishDate = Calendar1.SelectedDate;      
}

<asp:Calendar OnDayRender="Calendar_DayRender" />
```

Comment: what is the codes on  protected void Calendar1_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) ?